# How do i display card with different items when key pass through navigator in react native

Tags: react-native

When pass the item to the next screen through navigator of radio.js the other screen attendence.js card shows all item details with same id in the card with multiple times when an C# API is called in attendancjs.

I want  to show different items in the card when calling an API in attendance.js.

```
Radio.Js

onRadioBtnClick = () => {

     data.map((item) => 
    {
      if(item.attendanceType==checked)
    { 
      // if (index < item) {
      //   console.log(item)
      //   return item;
      // }
      // for(i=0;i<item.length;i++)
      // {
      //   elements=item[i]
        console.log({item})
      // }
         
        navigation.navigate('attendance',{item})
     
        
      
    } }
    );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xsme.png)

Attendance.js
return (

```
<ScrollView>

  {

  // {`${post.attendanceTime}`+ `${post.attendanceType}`}

  // console.log(item)

  data.map(() => (

   

  <View style={styles.view} >

    <Card style={styles.cardWrapper} >

      <View style={styles.card}>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Key:{item.id} {'\n'} 

         Latitude:{item.latitude} {'\n'} Longitude:{item.longitude}{'\n'}

          Attentance Time:{item.attendanceTime} {'\n'} 

          Attentance:{`${item.attendanceType}`}{item.attendanceType=="i"? (<Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../assests/checked.png')} /> ):(<Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../assests/delete.png')} />)}

          {'\n'}

          Employee Name: {item.userInfo.displayName} 

          </Text>

      </View>

    </Card>

  </View>

  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing object  `navigation.navigate('attendance',{item})` from `Radio.js` and in `Attendance.js` you are iterate over `data` array and display only `item`(which is one object) to length of data. So it will take length of data and display one item which is passed from `Radio.js`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249892/discussion-on-answer-by-asmeeta-rathod-how-do-i-display-card-with-different-item).